Removing the space on markdown page
I am unable to remove the space in the sides of the webpage even though the width is set as 12.
Over 30% of the space is lost.

If you are working in quarto then you can use the column value to set object width for overflow content.
Option 1: Fenced Div
As a fenced div for any arbitrary content:
:::{.column-body-outset}
Outset content...
:::


Option 2: Code Chunk Argument
Or in code chunks, which is the present use case.
```{r}
#| column: body-outset

knitr::kable(
  mtcars[1:6, 1:10]
)
```

See documentation for additional options.
Option 3: Rmarkdown with fig.fullwidth=TRUE chunk argument
If not wanting to use quarto for rendering, a wider figure can still be achieved with chunk options.
```{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=2, fig.fullwidth=TRUE}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .2)); plot(sunspots)
```

From the R Markdown book section on full width figures.
